# Is traffic a countable noun or an uncountable noun?

Tags: nouns, present-tense, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

#### Example sentence:

`"Not much/many traffic passes this way."`

Comment: If it were _many_, it would modify _traffics_, not _traffic_. If you want a singular _traffic_, you have to have a singular _much_.

Comment: It will be *a lot of* traffic.. NOT *many* traffic..,

Comment: When deciding if a noun is acting countably or uncountably, it is not useful to use "*a lot of [noun]*" as, in this case, the noun can be countable or uncountable: "A lot of guidance" - "A lot of sheep." - "A lot of apples." However, "much" is used only with uncountable nouns and many is used only with countable nouns,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traffic, like most things English speakers think of as an aggregate whole (equipment, weather), is an uncountable noun. It is a singular uncountable (yes you can have plural uncountable nouns). "... much traffic" is the correct form.